# Sitecore Clear Cache Programmatically

Tags: web-services, caching, sitecore, staging

I am trying to publish programmatically in Sitecore. Publishing works fine. But doing so  programmatically doesn't clear the sitecore cache. What is the best way to clear the cache programmatically?

I am trying to use the webservice that comes with the staging module. But I am getting a Bad request exception(***Exception: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.***). I tried to increase the service receivetimeout and sendtimeout on the client side config file but that didn't fix the problem. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated?

I am using the following code:

```cs
CacheClearService.StagingWebServiceSoapClient client = new CacheClearService.StagingWebServiceSoapClient();
CacheClearService.StagingCredentials credentials = new CacheClearService.StagingCredentials();

credentials.Username = "sitecore\adminuser";
credentials.Password = "***********";
credentials.isEncrypted = false;

bool s = client.ClearCache(true, dt, credentials);
```

I am using following code to do publish.

```cs
 Database master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
 Database web = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("web");

 string userName = "default\adminuser";

 Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User user = Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.FromName(userName, true);

 user.RuntimeSettings.IsAdministrator = true;

 using (new Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserSwitcher(user))
 {

     Sitecore.Publishing.PublishOptions options = new Sitecore.Publishing.PublishOptions(master, web,
     Sitecore.Publishing.PublishMode.Full, Sitecore.Data.Managers.LanguageManager.DefaultLanguage, DateTime.Now);

     options.RootItem = master.Items["/sitecore/content/"];
     options.Deep = true;
     options.CompareRevisions = true;
     options.RepublishAll = true;
     options.FromDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);

     Sitecore.Publishing.Publisher publisher = new Sitecore.Publishing.Publisher(options);
     publisher.Publish();
  }
```

Comment: What code are you using to publish your items programatically? Because it should do cache clearing and staging anyway.

Comment: Alex is right.  The caching should be handled by the publishing process automatically.  It would be helpful if you could post the code you use to publish, as that may be the underlying cause of the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Sitecore 6, the CacheManager class has a static method that will clear all caches. The ClearAll() method is obsolete.

```cs
Sitecore.Caching.CacheManager.ClearAllCaches();
```

Comment: In case you found this via Google and you're slow like me, this lives in the Sitecore.Kernel.dll (duh, I suppose...).

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick note, in Sitecore 6.3, that is not needed anymore. Caches are being cleared automatically after a change happens on a remote server.
Also, if you are on previous releases, instead of clearing all caches, you can do partial cache clearing.
There is a free shared source component called Stager that does that.
http://trac.sitecore.net/SitecoreStager
If you need a custom solution, you can simply extract the source code from there.

Comment: Thanks for that, makes the upgrade I am doing all the more worth while

Answer (score 3):

I got this from Sitecore support. It clears all caches:

```cs
Sitecore.Context.Database = this.WebContext.Database;
Sitecore.Context.Database.Engines.TemplateEngine.Reset();
Sitecore.Context.ClientData.RemoveAll();
Sitecore.Caching.CacheManager.ClearAllCaches();
Sitecore.Context.Database = this.ShellContext.Database;
Sitecore.Context.Database.Engines.TemplateEngine.Reset();
Sitecore.Caching.CacheManager.ClearAllCaches();
Sitecore.Context.ClientData.RemoveAll();
```

Comment: what type is the this object? is there any way to create it from linqpad?

Answer (score 2):

Via the [SDN](http://sdn.sitecore.net/FAQ/API/Clearing%20the%20cache%20programmatically.aspx):

```cs
HtmlCache cache = CacheManager.GetHtmlCache(Context.Site);

if (cache != null) {
  cache.Clear();
}
```

Comment: In the version I'm using (6.5) CacheManager.ClearAll() is a void method.  Are you sure you don't mean CacheManager.GetHtmlCache(Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext site) instead?

Comment: oops, just saw the SDN link there... you do! :)   HtmlCache cache = CacheManager.GetHtmlCache(Context.Site); 

  if (cache != null) { 
    cache.Clear(); 
  }

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box solution provided by Sitecore to clean caches (ALL of them) is utilized by the following page: `http://sitecore_instance_here/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx` and code behind looks like the following snippet:

```cs
foreach (var cache in Sitecore.Caching.CacheManager.GetAllCaches())
    cache.Clear();
```